# onscroll event not getting called in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, experience-builder-page

We have lwc component which is placed in aura community page.

This component has lwc-datatable and some other html tags.

I have tried attaching onscroll event on many different tags including datatable, but on none it is firing and calling attached method.

I also have tried appending onscroll event dynamically but there also it not calling. Attached is the below code, I have tried dynamically.
js file

```
scrollCheck(event){
    console.log('Current value of the input: ' + event.target.scrollTop);
    console.log('Current value of the input: ' + event.target.scrollBottom);
}

renderedCallback()
{
    var div= this.refs.myDiv;
    console.log(':div:',div)
    div.onscroll = this.scrollCheck;
}
```

html

```
<template>
<div class="slds-p-around_small" id="scroll_container" lwc:ref="myDiv" >
</div>
```

html when onscroll was added on element itself.

```
 <template>
    <div class="slds-p-around_small" id="scroll_container" lwc:ref="myDiv" >
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: couldn't find anything on previous question available on stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is more related to browser `onscroll` event rather than LWC.

For capturing scroll events , we need to define the scrolling container using css `overflow-y` (for vertical scroll) property.

We need to define the scrolling area using below css :

```
.scrollContainer {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here , we can use `max-height` or `height` property. I've used `max-height` since it enables us to set scrolling threshold explicitly.

As an example , I've applied `onscroll` event to the datatable as below :

```
<div class="scrollContainer" onscroll={scrollCheck}>
    <lightning-datatable
      key-field="id"
      data={recordsToDisplay}
      columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
scrollCheck(event){
    console.log('Current value of the input: ' + event.target.scrollTop);
    console.log('Current value of the input: ' + event.target.scrollBottom);
  }
```

**Console**
[image]

More info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event